# Saber si una etiquete html tiene un atributo por jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, imagen, atributos

Tengo imagenes con el atributo ALT completo (caso1), otras imagenes lo tienen vacío(caso2), y otras directamente les falta el atributo(caso3).

Con las imagenes que tienen el atributo con valor, todo bien, no necesito hacer nada. EL segundo caso lo tengo resuelto, el problema está en el tercer caso.

Hice un código para poner valor al atributo ALT cuando este esté vacio (caso2). Lo que no puedo hacer es agregar el atributo cuando directamente no exista en el codigo (caso3)

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("img").each(function() {
    if($(this).attr("alt") === ''){
    $(this).attr("alt", "contiene una imagen");

    }
  });
});

</script>
```

Este código, repito, sirve para agregar valor a todas las imagnes que tengan ALT="". Me falta resolver Como agregar el atributo a quienes no tengan, sin pisar el resto de las etiquetas que estén bien.

Espero haber sido claro, sino me preguntan! gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Estimado:

revisando su código, debe agregar una condición mas a su sentencia if, quedando de la siguiente manera:

```js
if($(this).attr("alt") === '' || $(this).attr("alt")==null){
    $(this).attr("alt", "contiene una imagen");
}
```

Espero le haya sido de utilidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! Fue rápido y me sirvió!! me salvaste!

Answer (score 2):

negando el `.is('[attr]')` pareciera funcionar

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("alt") === '') {
      $(this).attr("alt", "alt vacío");
    }
    if (!$(this).is("[alt]")) {
      $(this).attr("alt", "no tenía alt");
    }

  });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 320px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 5;
  border: 1px dashed #fe0;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img alt='' src=a />
<img alt='este tiene alt' src=b />
<img src=d />
```

Comment: Muchas gracias alo!!! espectacular, me sirve el codigo!!